# How to call a stored procedure from PyODBC on a Teradata database?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, odbc, teradata, pyodbc

I am running

```
cursor.execute("""{call myStoredProcedure('abc')}""")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] 'myStoredProcedure' is not a macro.  (-3855) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Why is Teradata thinking that myStoredProcedure is macro and not a stored procedure?

I am able to run the usual select commands on the database. I can also run the stored procedure from the Teradata SQL Assisstant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without the curly braces:

```
cursor.execute("""call myStoredProcedure('abc')""")
```

And/or check the setting for the [DisableCALLToEXECConversion](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/Connectivity/B035_2509_082K/2509appe.15.3.html) option